# Set-Content Error : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (Powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scripting

What I'm trying to do here is delete all shared folders on my computer except for the default ones, which I'm removing with a single space before I loop through. It was working for about 10 minutes when all I of the sudden I get an error message saying that my Set-Content command won't go through because "it is being used by another process." Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Side Note: I know that `net share %%s /delete` is echoed out. I just wanted to see what will be deleted before I actually put it into effect.

`DeletingSharedFiles.bat`:

```
set /p name= "Name of the Admin user  |  "
net share> "C:\Users\%name%\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt"

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command 
"C:\Users\%name%\Desktop\SharedFiles.ps1"

for /f "tokens=1" %%s in (C:\Users\%name%\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt) do(
    echo net share %%s /delete  
)
```

`SharedFiles.ps1`

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:name\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt") | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "ADMIN\$", ""} | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "C\$", ""} | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "IPC\$", ""} |  
Set-Content "C:\Users\$env:name\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt"
```

Output of `DeletingSharedFiles.bat`

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 
'C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt' because it is being used
by another process.
At C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\SharedFiles.ps1:5 char:1
+ Set-Content "C:\Users\$env:name\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Comment: presumably you have tried to access the file before the previous process had entirely finished using the file. the solution seems likely to be adding a delay between accesses to the file. ///// as an aside ... WHY are you doing this in such a bizarre way? all of this can be done in powershell with no need for a BAT file.

Answer (score 2):

You are over complicating things:

- there is absolutly no need for a temporary file, neither in batch nor in PowerShell.
- to drop the shares which should stay from output, use a findstr /v
- the `for /f` has `tokens=1` as default, that doesn't have to be expressed.

So a single cmd line should do:

```
for /f %A in ('net share ^| findstr /IV "^Admin\$ ^C\$ ^IPC\$" ^| findstr ":\\"') do @Echo net share %A /del
```

or in a batch file:

```
@Echo off
for /f %%A in (
    'net share ^| findstr /IV "^Admin\$ ^C\$ ^IPC\$" ^| findstr ":\\"'
) do Echo net share %%A /del
```

A PowerShell script to do the complete task (requires Win10):

```
Get-SmbShare | Where-Object Name -notmatch "^Admin\$|^C\$|^IPC\$" | Remove-SMBShare -WhatIf
```

**Your** Powershellscript could be simplified:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:name\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt") -replace "^ADMIN\$|^C\$|^IPC\$" |  
Set-Content "C:\Users\$env:name\Desktop\SharedFiles.txt"
```

But keep in mind that by deleting these share names the `for /f` in **your** batch will ignore leading delimiters and then take the resource name/description as the 1st token.

---

All in all ***here*** a mixed batch/PowerShell script is neither usefull nor neccessary.